# libvlc will not compile without the library gl

Tags: gcc, libvlc, yocto

I am trying to compile libvlc for headless linux. i have made it further by adding

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " libvlc"
```

to my image with will build without x11 but it still fails on:

```
/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

how can i get it to built successfully?

**UPDATE:**

I am using Yocto 2.0 (Jethro) which is using VLC 2.2.1

i have a vlc_%.bbappends that i have now changed it to below with the suggested --disable-glx:

```
REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11"

DEPENDS_remove = " \
virtual/libsdl libsdl-image \
libxpm libxinerama fluidsynth \
libnotify gtk+ \
xcb-util-keysyms \
"

DEPENDS_append = " \
"

EXTRA_OECONF_remove = "\
--enable-xvideo \
--enable-sdl \
--enable-realrtsp \
"

EXTRA_OECONF += " \
--disable-xcb \
--disable-freetype \
--disable-fontconfig \
--disable-sdl \
--disable-sdl-image \
--disable-vdpau \
--disable-xvideo \
"

EXTRA_OECONF_append = " \
--disable-glx \
"

PACKAGECONFIG_remove = " \
svg \
svgdec \
samba \
freerdp \
gnome-vfs \
vorbis \
"
```

But i get this warning:

```
WARNING: QA Issue: vlc: configure was passed unrecognised options: --disable-glx [unknown-configure-option]
```

and it still fails on:

```
ld: cannot find -lGL
```

**Update 2**

looking at vlc/vlc-2.2.1-r0/configure.ac on line 3000

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([EGL], [egl], [
  have_egl="yes"
], [
  have_egl="no"
])
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_EGL], [test "${have_egl}" = "yes"])

have_gl="no"
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GL], [gl], [
  have_gl="yes"
], [
  AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
#ifdef _WIN32
# include <GL/glew.h>
#endif
#include <GL/gl.h>
]], [
    [int t0 = GL_TEXTURE0;]])
  ], [
    GL_CFLAGS=""
    have_gl="yes"
    AS_IF([test "${SYS}" != "mingw32"], [
      GL_LIBS="-lGL"
    ], [
      GL_LIBS="-lopengl32"
    ])
  ])
])
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_GL], [test "${have_gl}" = "yes"])
```

there is no way to disable gl. and i am not sure how it checks for package gl to be built. there is no --disable-gl like the rest of the options.

Comment: Which version of yocto are you using? In some versions, --disable-glx, has been used during configuration to disable OpenGL. Does your version use that?

Comment: @Anders --disable-glx sounds like the right thing for a non-X11 build since GLX is literally "GL for X11"?

Comment: @Bbbh The vlc recipe in meta-multimedia requires X11. If you have modified it or are using another recipe, please post it here.